# C# Faster generation of MD5 hashes

Tags: c#

I have a project where I have been given a MD5 hash of a number between 1 and 2 billion, and I have to write a distributed program which obtains the number by brute force. I have successfully coded this program and it works. I was wondering if there is a way to speed up the generation of hashes?

Here is my current function to generate the hashes:

```
    static string generateHash(string input)
    {
        MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();
        byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input));
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Generating them once and then loading them from a file is an obvious idea.

Comment: Create the hashes while the MD5 object is still defined would probably help. Defining it, letting it dispose, then re-instantiating it for the next generation is resource heavy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [BitConverter.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97.aspx)

```
static string generateHash(string input)
{
  MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();
  byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input));
  return BitConverter.ToString(data);
}
```

Comment: Beware, this snipped doesn't replace the one in the question, since it returns a string of hexadecimal pairs separated **by hyphens**.

Comment: Just add `.Replace("-", "")` to the returned value.

Comment: Sure, but then you won't always end up with a faster MD5 hash generator

Comment: Who uses MD5 thses days anyway? (Question is from 2012)

Comment: Probably no one should, just wanted to warn anyone from copying-pasting if they were expecting the same input as in the question :)